# Beeware ModuleNotFoundError with cv2

Tags: python, opencv, python-venv, modulenotfounderror, beeware

I try to create a python app which run with open cv by beeware in python. I can run the program by briefcase dev. But after I pack it into a exe file and try to run, it return ModuleNotFoundError.

[image]

It is my first time try to pack a python program into exe. It seems that I missed some steps, but I have no idea in it.

Comment: opencv is a native library.

Comment: always put error message as text, not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a package to your app, you must list it in the `requires` section of your pyproject.toml file. For details, see the ["third-party" page](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-7.html#running-the-updated-app) of the BeeWare tutorial.